# Django: How to access a function on the model during instantiation?

Tags: django

I have a custom function in a form that I would like to reuse. Hence I pushed it into the model so that the form can still access it and I could access it from elsewhere as well.

Now on my demo page upon instantiation of that model, I need access to that function `round_time_to_nearest_quarter()`. But the instance hasn't been created yet, hence how do I access the function?  It is a chicken and egg situation:

```
event = c3.event_set.create(                        
                    due_date_time = (???) round_time_to_nearest_quarter() + timezone.timedelta(days=1, hours=3),                        
                    )
```

Is there a better strategy to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some function, which is not dependent on any model, put this method to your utils.py file.